# RubyMotion: How to remove the launch activity for Android?

Tags: android, rubymotion

I crated an Android project using the hello-world template, and want to remove the launch activity which contains the made by `RubyMotion`.

By the way, I am using the `Starter` plan of `RubyMotion`?